# List of KMM Sealed Classes in Swift showing as empty when it isn't

Tags: swift, kotlin-multiplatform, sealed-class

I am trying to build an autocomplete text field in swift, but am having a strange problem with my source data, which is a list of sealed classes from a KMM module.

My code is adapted from this answer: [SwiftUI example for autocompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62176306/swiftui-example-for-autocompletion)

I have modified it to use a generic type for the list of possible options, and also pass a function to get the string value from the type.

The source list of options is coming from a KMM project and is an array/list of a sealed class.

The source data is correctly being passed to the struct, and when I display a list of the options on screen (in the VStack), it is displaying as expected.

However, in my `makePrediction` function, the list of predictableValues is empty.

If I pass a list of strings to my `AutoCompleteTextField` then the list isn't empty and it works as expected.

Printing `predictableValues` in the init block works, displaying them in the VStack works, so why is my list suddenly empty when I try to use it in `makePrediction`? (Yet if I just use plain strings as my type, the list isn't empty)

Here's my code for the AutoCompleteTextField

```
struct AutoCompleteTextField<T: Hashable>: View {
  var optionText: (T) -> String
  var predictableValues: Array<T>
  @State var textFieldInput: String = ""
  @State var predictedValue: Array<T> = []
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading){
      PredictingTextField(predictableValues: self.predictableValues, predictedValues: self.$predictedValue, textFieldInput: self.$textFieldInput, optionText: optionText)
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
      VStack{
        ScrollView{
          VStack{
            ForEach(self.predictedValue, id: \.self) { suggestion in
              ZStack {
                Text(optionText(suggestion))
              }
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
              .onTapGesture {
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }.padding()
  }
}


struct PredictingTextField<T: Hashable>: View {
  var optionText: (T) -> String
  /// All possible predictable values. Can be only one.
  var predictableValues: Array<T>
  /// This returns the values that are being predicted based on the predictable values
  @Binding var predictedValues: Array<T>
  /// Current input of the user in the TextField. This is Binded as perhaps there is the urge to alter this during live time. E.g. when a predicted value was selected and the input should be cleared
  @Binding var textFieldInput: String
  /// The time interval between predictions based on current input. Default is 0.1 second. I would not recommend setting this to low as it can be CPU heavy.
  @State var predictionInterval: Double?
  /// Placeholder in empty TextField
  @State var textFieldTitle: String?
  @State private var isBeingEdited: Bool = false
  init(predictableValues: Array<T>, predictedValues: Binding<Array<T>>, textFieldInput: Binding<String>, textFieldTitle: String? = "", predictionInterval: Double? = 0.1, optionText: @escaping (T) -> String){
    self.predictableValues = predictableValues
    self._predictedValues = predictedValues
    self._textFieldInput = textFieldInput
    self.textFieldTitle = textFieldTitle
    self.predictionInterval = predictionInterval
    self.optionText = optionText
  }
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      ForEach(self.predictableValues, id: \.self){ value in
        Text(optionText(value)) //This works correctly with both string and sealed class
      }
    }
    TextField(self.textFieldTitle ?? "", text: self.$textFieldInput, onEditingChanged: { editing in self.realTimePrediction(status: editing)}, onCommit: { self.makePrediction()})
  }
  /// Schedules prediction based on interval and only a if input is being made
  private func realTimePrediction(status: Bool) {
    self.isBeingEdited = status
    if status == true {
      Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: self.predictionInterval ?? 1, repeats: true) { timer in
        self.makePrediction()
        if self.isBeingEdited == false {
          timer.invalidate()
        }
      }
    }
  }
  /// Makes prediciton based on current input
  private func makePrediction() {
    print(self.predictableValues) //the list is empty here when using the LocationOption sealed class, but correctly holds the list of strings when using strings
    self.predictedValues = []
    if !self.textFieldInput.isEmpty{
      for value in self.predictableValues {
        if optionText(value).lowercased().contains(self.textFieldInput.lowercased()) {
          self.predictedValues.append(value)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
AutoCompleteTextField(
     optionText: {$0.text()},
     predictableValues: state.basicInfo.locationOptions //Not working correctly
)
    

AutoCompleteTextField(
    optionText: {$0},
    predictableValues: [
       "ABC", "DEF" //Works correctly
    ]
)
```

And here's the KMM class I'm trying to use:

```
sealed class LocationOption {
    data class TypeA(val value: database.TypeA) : LocationOption()
    data class TypeB(val value: database.TypeB) : LocationOption()

    fun text() = when (this) {
        is TypeA-> value.r_name
        is TypeB-> value.name
    }

    fun location() = when (this) {
        is TypeB-> Location(value.lat, value.lng, 0.0)
        is TypeA-> Location(value.lat, value.lng, 0.0)
    }
}
```